# What version of Ruby ships with OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, ruby

I have the default Ruby 1.8.7 on 10.7 (Lion), and I'm wondering if Mountain Lion upgrades this to the 1.9.x series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my 10.8.1 system:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ian [ian@Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro] [15:48]
> which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ian [ian@Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro] [17:49]
> ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```